# H2o R package: multiple ifelse conditions in h2o

Tags: r, if-statement, h2o

I am trying to write a simple ifelse function in h2o R.

```
my_cl$Seg<-ifelse((my_cl$predict==0), '1', ifelse(my_cl$predict==1), '2','0'))
```

Single ifelse works with no issues.
But when I try to to even write a code with just two ifelse it gives me an error:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in "my_cl$Seg<-ifelse((my_cl$predict==0), '1', ifelse(my_cl$predict==1), '2','0'))"
```

In regular R it would be correct.
If I remove a )

```
Error in ifelse((my_cl$predict == 0), "1", ifelse(my_cl$predict == 1),  : unused arguments ("2", "0")
```

Is it because in h2o the multiple ifelse are not supported? 
I tried to replace `ifelse` with `h2o.ifelse`   - same errors.
Thank you

Comment: Please update your code to contain a minimal, reproducible example of the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  (you can use the built-in iris dataset to make this reproducible).

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets were misplaced

```
my_cl$Seg<-ifelse(my_cl$predict==0, 
              '1', 
              ifelse(my_cl$predict==1, '2','0'))
```

Comment: Thank you Patrik!. My bad, it's an obvious one.

Comment: happy to help, fyi, if it solved the problem you should accept the answer so the question is marked as completed